# Docker Toolbox refused to connect on the browser - Tried different solutions - Windows 7

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 7.
Everything has been installed correctly.

Now I try to build and run a DockerFile.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get update -yq \
   && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
   && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
   && apt-get install nodejs -yq \
   && apt-get clean -y

ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

VOLUME /app/logs

CMD npm run start
```

After successfully running the command line `docker build -t test .` and `docker run -it -d -p 3306:3306 test`, I try to access it via my browser by doing :

```
http://192.168.99.100:3306
```

which correspond to http://[docker-machine-ip]:port

But it refuses to connect.

After searching on the internet, I tried several solutions:

**1. Use the container IP**

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' [id]


http://[containerIP]:port
```

**2. Add port forwarding on Oracle VM defaut machine**

```
VirtualBox -> Machine settings -> Network -> Adapter 1 (NAT) -> Advanced, Port Forwarding
```

- name : test
- Host ip : 127.0.0.1
- Host port : 3306
- Guest port : 3306

I even tried by putting Guest IP to 192.168.99.100 and letting Host IP to empty.

**3. Try different ports**

I tried differents ports to see if it was not caused by a port already opened.

I even tried the option `--publish-all` (-P) but as a result, I don't have any ports showing on `docker ps -a`

```
docker run -it -d -P test
```

**4. Deactivate the windows firewall**

Both public and private.

None of those solutions worked for me and I don't know what to do next.

Any help ? I would appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: 3306 is usually the MySQL port; Node Express applications are typically on port 3000.  Can you double-check that you have the right port number (especially the second number in a `docker run -p` option)?

Comment: The other common cause of this problem is an Express application not explicitly set to listen on the special IPv4 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried many ports (even random one) and I paid attention that the port put after the IP is the one before ":" in docker run command. What's your suggestion then for the other common cause ?